# How can I pass a state variable into render object in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass a state variable called 'imageSize' into a map render object, but I can't figure out how to do this, I have 2 state variables:

```
const [searchImages, setSearchImages] = useState([]);    
const [imageSize, setImageSize] = useState("regular");
```

I currently have mapped over searchImages with no problems, but when I try to add 'imageSize' into my img src , it doesn't work, like so:

```
    {searchImages.map(item => (
           <img className='image-item' key={item.id} src={item.urls.imageSize} alt='cool'/>
    ))}
```

Could you provide advice on how I can achieve this.

Comment: maybe u want `item.urls[imageSize]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `imageSize` as a state to trigger different image size in the object `item -> urls`, therefore you can not use dot notation, but you need bracket notation as:

```js
{searchImages.map(item => (
  <img className='image-item' key={item.id} src={item.urls[`${imageSize}`]} alt='cool'/>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine both states into one, which is not required. As you are using `searchImages` as an array of items and you need the `imageSize` to be used as size for the image, you can try doing this:

```js
{searchImages.map(item => (
    <img className='image-item' key={item.id} src={`${item.urls}${imageSize}`} alt='cool'/>
))}
```

If you want to add any "-" or "/" as a combination for both the variables you can do something like this `` {`${item.urls}-${imageSize}`} `` or `` {`${item.urls}/${imageSize}`} ``